# Polylang не работает с кастомными постами

Tags: wordpress

Делаю мультиязычный сайт на wp и у меня там большая часть постов - это кастомные посты. Мультиязычность реализуется с помощью плагина polylang. Хотя в документации плагина указано, что он работает с кастомными постами - у меня в админке нет возможности добавить перевод для них.

Как можно решить эту проблему? Чтение гугла не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Включите поддержку кастомных типов записей в настройках плагина.
Процес описан в [документации](https://polylang.pro/doc/multilingual-custom-post-types-and-taxonomies/) плагина.